# Creating multiple matplotlib charts from one function which is taking in a list of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, charts, bar-chart

[image]I am basically taking a csv file and need to make a bar chart out of each column from the chart.
What I currently have is the function I have created takes each numerical column and creates a bar chart of each unique element and how many times it has occurred in the column of the data source.

My problem is that every new graph I plot it overlaps and is from the same "figure".

Is there any way to make a function that will create the chart plot and make it "unique" to its other fellow charts

Answer (score 0):

plt.figure(postition) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to create figure each time your function read and plot the column.
I suggest that you use the OOP of Matplotlib.
For example use

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#then in any place of your code, you can use, for example
ax.plot(x,y)
```

To make a different figure for each loop,
put the `fig, ax = plot.subplots()` inside the loop.
If you want to make various plots into single figure, create the figure outside the loop.
Here is perfect tutorial:
https://realpython.com/python-matplotlib-guide/

Consider give a minimal-example, so that others can help you better.